# Add CSS class to only those links that do not have 'title' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
        <td><a href src="xxx" title="">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
        <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add some CSS class to

```
<td><a href src="xxx" title="">Link</a></td>
```

How can I make this with jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: actually in your code they have `title`attribute, but it is empty

Comment: @Gainsky update the title of the question to `...of links having empty title attribute value`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `src` attribute instead of the `href`? There is no `src` attribute defined for the `a` element....

Comment: It's my mistake ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this with jQuery or JS

You can do it with [`attribute equals selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/),

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td > a[title='']").addClass("something");
```

Also note that you have an invalid html, `tbody` should be the immediate child of a `table` element.

```
<table>
  <tbody> <!-- note the tbody here -->
    <tr>
      <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
      <td><a href src="xxx" title="">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
      <td><a href src="xxx" title="Some text">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eoohchjw/)

Answer (score 8):

No need of using jQuery to add a CSS class. You can use attribute-value selector in CSS.

```
a[title=""] {
    color: red;
}
```

To add class by using jQuery other than just styling purpose

```
$('a[title=""]').addClass('someClass');
```

---

To select elements which **do not have `title` attribute**

```
a:not([title]) {
    color: red;
}
```

Same selector can be use in jQuery.

```
$('a:not([title])')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out, you can achieve this with css. However, if you are **set** on using javascript or jQuery, you could use the following;

> **note** - I do not recommend this solution, I have posted this purely because you asked for a javascript/jQuery solution. Go with the CSS
>   only option.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
  if(!links[i].hasAttribute('title')){
   // Link without title attribute

   links[l].style.color = 'red';

   // Or if you want to add a class...

   links[l].setAttribute('class', links[l].getAttribute('class') + 'red');
  }
}
```

Comment: would be easier to loop through with `each`.
`$("a").each(function(){
  // do something
})`